# Recursive generics mapping

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a `T MapObject<T>(this ManagementBaseObject so)` method where I map data from a `ManagementBaseObject` into a POCO.

Sometimes the data in `ManagementBaseObject` may have nested data also of type `ManagementBaseObject`, effectively meaning I need to call `T MapObject<T>(this ManagementBaseObject so)` recursively only this time with a different `T` as output. I can access the new `T` as a `TypeInfo` object but the way I see it I only have two options:

1. Keep the generic `T MapObjecT<T>(this ManagementBaseObject so)` which means I need to use something reflection to create a call to `MapObject<T>` using `MakeGenericMethod`
2. Create a private non-generic `object MapObject(this ManagementBaseObject so, Type t)` and make the generic method call this one.

Both seem to have disadvantages: the first is ugly and relies on reflection, the second is subject to boxing and unboxing of the returned object. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Is there a common interface possible between the recursed somethings?

Comment: @PatrickArtner to be more concrete, the `Something` is `ManagementBaseObject`

Comment: Could you show us the method or excerpts of it?

Comment: Maybe use Automapper or any other mapping library?

Comment: AFAIK option 2. is not an issue if you don't map into primitives or `struct`s. Heap-allocated objects don't need to be boxed.

Comment: "the second is subject to boxing and unboxing of the returned object". And so is the use of reflection.